# how to compare two sql query values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables StockOutward and product outward..I have to fetch the sum(qty) that not equals to sum(qty) stockOutward..

**StockOutward**

```
Id ProductId Qty Location Orderid

1     7       2     2        38
2     8       1     2        38
3     7       1     2        38
```

**ProductOutward**

```
Id ProductId Qty Location Orderid

1     7       12     2        38
2     8        1     2        38
```

I need the output from stockoutward as ProductId 7

I have used the below query

```
Select
    sum(qty) as Qty,ProductId 
from 
    StockOutward 
where 
    Orderid='38' 
group by 
    ProductId 

Union

Select 
    sum(qty) as Qty,
    ProductId 
from 
    ProductOutward 
where 
    Orderid='38' 
group by 
    ProductId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `JOIN` and filter for inequality:

```
SELECT
    s.ProductId
FROM (
    SELECT
        ProductId,
        SumQty = SUM(Qty)
    FROM StockOutward
    GROUP BY ProductId
)s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ProductId,
        SumQty = SUM(Qty)
    FROM ProductOutward
    GROUP BY ProductId
)p
    ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
    AND p.SumQty <> s.SumQty
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select sum(qty) as Qty,ProductId from StockOutward where Orderid='38' group by ProductId 
except
Select sum(qty) as Qty,ProductId from ProductOutward where Orderid='38' group by ProductId
```